# How can I get the specific colors that are being used in my vim ruby plugin / theme?

Tags: vim

I looking for the specific hex colors that are being used in my color scheme when I'm editing ruby files with vim. How would I find such information?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GUI, you could use gpick:

```
 sudo apt-get install gpick
```

The colors themselves are reliant on what terminal you use. They are all the named colors, i.e. orange, blue, etc. The specific hex codes for these are very reliant on how your terminal interprets them (at least from my experience). The different color themes are stored here:

```
 /usr/share/vim/vim73/colors
```